# Channel Images import hangs

Tags: channel-images

I have a site where Channel Images' Upload works and images are displayed but Import simply hangs.

Also, Channel Images is generating long randomly-named directories in the site's home directory and saving images there.

All the settings seem correct and everything passes with Test Location in Upload Location Settings.

Anybody seen this before?

Comment: Did you ever get this working?

Answer (score 0):

It was a while back but I think it was a permissions issue on this instance of the site -- the /htdocs folder itself had permissions that were too strict.